HttpClient in .NET 8 Windows Service Ignores System Proxy Settings
After migrating a server application from .NET Framework 4.7.2 to .NET 8, HTTP requests made by the server application stopped working because the HttpClient doesn't use the proxy configured in the system's proxy settings. The server runs as a Windows Service.
More details:

HttpClient is used to make requests.

If I explicitly configure HttpClient to use a WebProxy with the same proxy IP address and port as the system proxy settings, the requests work.

If I create a console application using the same code (without explicitly configuring the proxy) and run it under the same user as the Windows Service, the requests succeed.

Browsers also correctly use the system proxy under the same user.


Have anyone experienced such behaviour? What could cause the Windows Service in .NET 8 to ignore the system proxy settings, and what should I focus on to resolve this issue? Thanks a lot.

Windows services typically run under the LocalSystem user not the current user account, as such any user proxy configuration will not work. Debugging, or running console apps will execute the code under your windows user, that is why you cannot reproduce.

@AnthonyG. this service runs under current user

I suggest you could consider re-checking how you run this windows service, it is log on as the local service or local system. Maybe the user don't have permission to access the internet options or proxy settings.
I suggest you could firstly run below command of the service account to see if it apply the proxy:
netsh winhttp show proxy

Besides, I suggest you could make sure the proxy settings is for the local system and make sure the service is run as the local system to test again.

when I run netsh winhttp show proxy, I see the user has set the proxy correctly. I tried to create very simple application which performs some url requests (without proxy specification in the code) and tried to run it as a service under the same user. It inherits proxy settings, there is no problem. There must be something in my application, but I have no idea what. Maybe some settings after the upgrade from .net framework 4.7.2 to .net 8.. idk

How you register the httpclient inside the asp.net core?
